# Windows: launch process on specific processor group

Tags: windows, process, numa

I have a Windows C++ application which launches a bunch of processes, which work on a queue of jobs that use multiple cores to do some work.

I am running into a problem with systems of more than 64 cores - for example, on a 80-core system, only the first 40 cores are used.

From what I can gather, such a system would have two processor groups.  How can I launch my processes so half are confined to processor group 1 and half to processor group 2?

Comment: [*An application that requires the use of multiple groups so that it can run on more than 64 processors must explicitly determine where to run its threads and is responsible for setting the threads' processor affinities to the desired groups.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ProcThread/processor-groups)

Comment: The processor group for a child process should be assigned round robin by default. I guess if it's not for some reason, then you could create a job object for each processor group (via `JobObjectGroupInformation`) and manually implement your own round-robin assignment of each process to a job.